# Another undergrad or a masters degree before PhD?

Tags: masters, undergraduate

I have a low GPA (2.97) and by the time I graduate this coming Summer I'll have roughly >3.01.

I'm debating whether I should add another major and not graduate in Summer or graduate in Summer and get a masters. The assumption is that I will get a 4.0 in either the added major or the masters.

What is the better choice/what looks more attractive or makes up for my GPA more? My only scar on my CV is my GPA as I excel everywhere else.

Background:

- I study computer science and the masters or other undergrad major would be mathematics.
- I do research in artificial intelligence and would be focusing on cog sci programs for my PhD.
- I want to get into a top school for my PhD.

For clarity:

- I'd be adding on a major and would eventually graduate with both CS and math.
- My PI has said he'd pay for my remaining undergrad provided I stay in the lab (which is a good thing; he's a top AI researcher at my uni)

Update: I've decided that I'm adding a math major and going to attempt to get a 4.0 for the remaining time here while continuing research.

Comment: I guess this would be better if you ask your advisor this question.

Comment: I have and it's a different answer depending on which adviser you speak with. My PI also has differing opinions as well. This question is mainly to get more opinions.

Comment: In that case, this question may end up being closed as primarily opinion-based...

Comment: @NatalieHogg I may be using opinion lightly when describing what I'm looking for with this question. Though, opinions will be a large portion of the reasoning behind answers to this question, those opinions are not solely based on personal preference - but hopefully more experience and knowledge of academic politics - and thus I don't think this question should be closed as it may serve as a general help for others in a situation similar to mine. If it is closed, though I'll repost it with wiser wording.

Comment: Assuming you get another major and assuming you get a 4.0, what will that bring your GPA up to?  Unfortunately, even with a 4.0 Masters, an undergrad GPA of 3.01 is going to be difficult to explain.  Top schools are going to filter applicants out using roughly a 3.5 GPA cutoff.

Comment: @Hobbes It would bring it up to roughly a 3.2-3.3. I also am a researcher and will have publications by then, have hopefully attended REUs, and already have corresponded with some profs at top schools. I believe if I keep up the political games I'll be able to get passed their hard cutoffs and have my apps considered in full. The only issue is my GPA. So, I am curious as to which option - masters or another major - proves most that my GPA is not my aptitude but merely me being confused and emotionally distraught (which is true).

Comment: 3.2 - 3.3 with strong research and recommendations will be more competitive.  I think this would be better than getting an MS if you are sure you want to pursue the PhD.  Even with a 4.0 in a MS, that undergrad GPA may come back to bite you.  Hard to say.  Which option is cheaper?

Answer (score 3):

To switch from CS to math, you have to show you have enough math courses.  You didn't talk about that.

Poor grades in the first two years don't matter very much.

Your grades in your math classes and your more theoretical CS classes will carry more weight than, say, a class in operating systems or a very coding-intensive class.

You might need to pick out the key classes you think support your application the most strongly, and put them in a table, showing the course title, brief description if the title is not self-explanatory, and the grade.

Financial considerations could be important.  If you would have to go into debt to finance further studies, then you might want to get a master's in CS, with a TA-ship, but load yourself up with math and math-oriented courses as part of the master's.

It's not clear to me where you would do the master's.  Are you thinking about doing it in the same university where you're doing the Bachelor's?  If not, moving to a new school brings a lot of unknowns.  On the other hand, if your current university is not a great fit for you, for whatever reason, then it could be beneficial to go elsewhere for a master's.

One difference between taking extra classes as an undergrad and doing a master's is that if you take a 500 level class where both seniors and first-year grad students are enrolled, expectations will be higher for the grad students.  AND note that as a grad student you would be expected to earn an A or A- (or a B in the worst case).

Note that if you want to take more math classes at your current institution, there are two additional options that you have not mentioned:
- just wait to graduate, and take some more classes
- go ahead and graduate, and then take some more classes as a non-matriculated student

If I were going to evaluate your admission application (that is a big if -- I have never sat on an admissions committee), I would want to see that after three years of college studies, you started to take things more seriously, you started to do very well, and you started to take more responsibility and initiative.

Taking the initiative means finding math classes that help you mature as a mathematician.

So, bottom line: I think you should expend your energy choosing classes wisely.  I think that matters more than exactly what your status is when you take those classes.